# Kill old process when using AWS codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS CodeDeploy to deploy a binary to an EC2 instance.

When I deploy a new version of the binary, do I need to tell CodeDeploy to kill the old running binary, and if so, what's the best way to do this.

Should I save the pid of the old process to a file & then kill it?

Or, does CodeDeploy automatically kill the old process?

Answer (score 0):

> does CodeDeploy automatically kill the old process?

It does not. You have to do it yourself. CD provides special [hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server) for that where you can perform such operation:

> ApplicationStop - This deployment lifecycle event occurs even before the application revision is downloaded. You can specify scripts for this event to gracefully **stop the application** or remove currently installed packages in preparation for a deployment. The AppSpec file and scripts used for this deployment lifecycle event are from the previous successfully deployed application revision.

AWS also [provides example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-wordpress-configure-content.html#tutorials-wordpress-configure-content-create-scripts) of how one can use `ApplicationStop` to stop wordpress. The other example is [SampleApp_Linux.zip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-github-upload-sample-revision.html#tutorials-github-upload-sample-revision-unixes) which you can download and inspect to check how `ApplicationStop` is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see where to download `SampleApp_Linux.zip` in the provided link.

Comment: @Roymunson You have to download from s3. In the link, they provide aws s3 cp commands to do it.